# case statement in where clause condition in sql

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a stored procedure like this:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[hr_SearchVacanciesAdmin]
    @SearchText NVARCHAR(50) = NULL,
    @CompanyName NVARCHAR(100) = NULL,
    @DutyStationID INT = NULL,
    @VacancyCategoryIDs VARCHAR(1000) = NULL,
    @Status INT,
    @Language INT = 1

BEGIN

SELECT * from table
where 
  deleted = 0
  and status = @status
  and catname  = &searchtext

..
..
..
END
```

I want to add case statement in where condition so that if @status = 4 then delete = is not checked. I tried following but not working

```
WHERE 
  1 = CASE 
        WHEN @Status = 4 
        THEN @status

        WHEN dbo.hr_Vacancies.Deleted = 0 
             --Search Criteria
             AND dbo.hr_Vacancies.Status = @Status 
        THEN @Status
      END
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You don't need a CASE statement to acheive this functionality. The following will do fine:

```
SELECT * 
from   table
where  (deleted = 0 OR @status=4)
and    status = @status
and    catname = @searchtext
```

Note also that your code refers to `&searchtext` in the `where` clause, but this should be `@searchtext` as per this answer (ie prefix with `@` not `&`).

Answer (score 1):

@RB is correct you don't need a case for that but you can use a case with this trick, which is useful in other scenarios as well:

```
 Where deleted = case @status when 4 then deleted else 0 end
```

Answer (score -1):

You may use this construct for the `SELECT` query to start with:

```
Select * from table
WHERE
((1 = CASE WHEN @Status = 4 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)
OR
dbo.hr_Vacancies.Deleted = 0)
AND
dbo.hr_Vacancies.Status = @Status
```

Comment: dwnvoted because expression in parentheses `(1 = CASE WHEN @Status = 4 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)
` is equivalent to `@Status = 4`